# activator dist do not packaging my project

Tags: java, scala, sbt, activator

```
lazy val xxxRoot = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(projectA, projectB, projectC)

lazy val xxxSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.xxx",
  version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
)

lazy val projectA = (project in file("pa"))
  .settings(xxxSettings: _*)

val projectB = (project in file("pb"))
  .settings(xxxSettings: _*)
  .dependsOn(projectA)

lazy val projectC = (project in file("pc"))
  .settings(xxxSettings: _*)
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava)
  .enablePlugins(SbtWeb)
  .enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)
  .dependsOn(projectA)
```

Here is my `build.sbt` at root path.
And my problem is:

When I run activator dist. `sbt` will compile `projectA` and `projectC`, but leave `projectB` alone. I suppose it might because `projectB` is not a dependency of any other project and also not a play application.

I can get jar package of `projectA` and `projectC`. But `projectB`'s jar was always not packaged even not compiled no matter what the `pb/build.sbt` is. I want to know how to force `sbt` compile `projectB` and package it using activator dist?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that no subproject `dependsOn` `projectB`. Perhaps you meant to have `projectC` `dependOn` `projectB` instead of `projectA`?

```
lazy val projectC = (project in file("pc"))
  .settings(xxxSettings: _*)
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava)
  .enablePlugins(SbtWeb)
  .enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)
  .dependsOn(projectB)
```